# Using CSS and HTML, Is it possible to have the user's clicking on a certain button change the style of a DIFFERENT element?

Tags: html, css

For instance, I'd like a column of buttons on the left:

```
Option 1

Option 2

Option 3

Option 4
```

And a column of paragraphs on the right:

```
OPTION 1 TEXT PARAGRAPH

OPTION 2 TEXT PARAGRAPH

OPTION 3 PHOTO LIBRARY

OPTION 4 REGISTRATION FORM
```

When the user clicks on `Option 1`, I'd like to have it do nothing except adjust the CSS style of `Option 1 TEXT PARAGRAPH` from `display: none;` to `display: block;`, and to change the styles of `Options 2-4` to `display: none;`.

This way only one category would be visible at a time.

I'm pretty familiar with HTML and CSS but haven't come across a need for this function before.

Unfortunately, I'm brand new to JavaScript and would prefer not to use it for this, if it's possible to handle with CSS. So my question is, is it?

By the way, I have searched a lot for an answer before creating a new account here to ask, and maybe I just can't figure out how to phrase this, but please forgive me if the answer exists elsewhere.

Comment: The simple thing is you try we help. This is not a coding service.

Comment: **"So my question is, is it?"**.  Yes, it is.  But in reality that's not your question.  You seem to be asking for someone to write the code for you, which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using labels and hidden radios.

```css
columnHolder {
  display:flex;
}
rightColumnItem {
  display:none; 
}
[linkedTo="option1"] {
  background:green;
}
[linkedTo="option2"] {
  background:gold;
}
[linkedTo="option3"] {
  background:tan;
}
[linkedTo="option4"] {
  background:gray;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display:none; 
}
#option1:checked ~ columnHolder rightColumn [linkedTo="option1"] {
  display:block;
}
#option2:checked ~ columnHolder rightColumn [linkedTo="option2"] {
  display:block;
}
#option3:checked ~ columnHolder rightColumn [linkedTo="option3"] {
  display:block;
}
#option4:checked ~ columnHolder rightColumn [linkedTo="option4"] {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioSelector" id="option1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radioSelector" id="option2">
<input type="radio" name="radioSelector" id="option3">
<input type="radio" name="radioSelector" id="option4">
<columnHolder>
  <leftColumn>
    <label for="option1"><div>Option 1</div><label>
    <label for="option2"><div>Option 2</div><label>
    <label for="option3"><div>Option 3</div><label>
    <label for="option4"><div>Option 4</div><label>
  </leftColumn>
  <rightColumn>
    <rightColumnItem linkedTo="option1">OPTION 1 TEXT PARAGRAPH</rightColumnItem>
 <rightColumnItem linkedTo="option2">OPTION 2 TEXT PARAGRAPH</rightColumnItem>
 <rightColumnItem linkedTo="option3">OPTION 3 PHOTO LIBRARY</rightColumnItem>
   <rightColumnItem linkedTo="option4">OPTION 4 REGISTRATION FORM</rightColumnItem>
  </rightColumn>
</columnHolder>
```

Comment: This feels like sorcery. I don't understand what I'm looking at but it works. Amazing answer, and thank you. I shall study this and implement it as soon as I figure it out!

Comment: It's pretty simple really. The 'label' tag is used to 'remote click' the radio boxes (with id tag). 
Then the css sibling selector displays based on the 'checked'. But in any case please select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it using javascript. You can add click event in the buttons and use id in the paragraphs. And then set html css property display using javascript. I do not think you can do this using css only.

Added fiddle link of the example

http://jsfiddle.net/cu2xaz86/12/

lets say below is your html. May be not exactly how you want.. but an example

```
<button onclick="javascript:op('s1')">
  Option 1
</button>
<button onclick="javascript:op('s2')">
Option 2
</button>
<button onclick="javascript:op('s3')">
Option 3
</button>
<button onclick="javascript:op('s1')">
Option 4
</button>

<span id="s1" style="display: none;">
OPTION 1 TEXT PARAGRAPH
</span>
<span id="s2" style="display: none;">
OPTION 2 TEXT PARAGRAPH
</span>
<span id="s3" style="display: none;">
OPTION 3 PHOTO LIBRARY
</span>
<span id="s4" style="display: none;">
OPTION 4 REGISTRATION FORM
</span>
```

and then the javascript function can be something like below , where you make all the element display none first and then set display block for the element you want to show.

```
function op1(v) {
    var x = document.getElementById("s1");
  x.style.display = "none";

  x = document.getElementById("s2");
  x.style.display = "none";

  x = document.getElementById("s3");
  x.style.display = "none";

  x = document.getElementById("s4");
  x.style.display = "none";

  x = document.getElementById(v);
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm just curious if you could explain how that fifth section of JS code works (what does the (v); part do)? Cheers mate.

Comment: The v part is just the argument in the javascript function. I will suggest you to do a javascript tutorial online, it will help.  You can see on button click there is a function call op('s1'). In runtime v will have s1 in this case .. so the first paragraph will be visible.